# App crashes on android 6 and above for camera startup permission

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I have designed an app which asks permission to allow the camera on startup. However, for Android 6 and above the app crashes as the

```
allow the access to camera Camera.open() return null
```

I have set the `camera.setDisplayOrentaion(90);` which is returning to Null.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to initialize the camera before the user grants the permission and `onRequestPermissionsResult` with `PERMISSION_GRANTED` is called on your `Activity`. See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for details on how to properly handle runtime permissions in your app.